# Grouped sections not displaying in tableview

Tags: ios, json, swift, uitableview

My entire table view is being written programmatically and the data is coming from JSON. I am trying to group the cells by the `customer` the code seems to be correct but no sections are showing up at all.

Here is the code:

**Portfolios.swift**

```
import UIKit

    struct Portfolios: Codable {
        let customer, serial, rma, model: String
        let manufacturer: String
    }
```

**PortfolioController.swift**

```
import UIKit

class PortfolioController: UITableViewController {

    var portfolios = [Portfolios]()
    var portfoliosDic = [String:[Portfolios]]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true
        view.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
        navigationItem.title = "Customer"
        fetchJSON()
    }

     func fetchJSON(){
        let urlString = "https://www.example.com/example/example.php"
        guard let url = URL(string: urlString) else { return }
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, _, error) in
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                if let error = error {
                    print("Failed to fetch data from url", error)
                    return
                }
                guard let data = data else { return }
                do {

                    let decoder = JSONDecoder()
                    decoder.keyDecodingStrategy = .convertFromSnakeCase
                    let res = try JSONDecoder().decode([Portfolios].self, from: data)
                    self.portfoliosDic = Dictionary(grouping: res, by: { $0.customer})
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        self.tableView.reloadData()
                    }
                    self.portfolios = try decoder.decode([Portfolios].self, from: data)

                    self.tableView.reloadData()

                } catch let jsonError {
                    print("Failed to decode json", jsonError)
                }

            }
        }.resume()
    }
    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return portfoliosDic.keys.count
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        let keys = Array(portfoliosDic.keys)
        let item = portfoliosDic[keys[section]]!
        return item.count
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = UITableViewCell(style: .subtitle, reuseIdentifier: "cellId")
            let keys = Array(portfoliosDic.keys)
            let arr = portfoliosDic[keys[indexPath.section]]!
            let customer = arr[indexPath.row]


let titleStr = [customer.serial, customer.manufacturer, customer.model].compactMap { $0 }.joined(separator: " - ")

        //cell.textLabel?.text = titleStr




        print(titleStr)
        // Get references to labels of cell
        cell.textLabel!.text = customer.serial


        return cell
    }

}
```

**UPDATE:**

Because it is a UIViewController Xcode told me to remove the `override func`

and I added `@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!`

(The end results is an empty table for some reason)

**Using a UITableViewController instead:**

```
import UIKit

class CustomerViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
    var sections = [Section]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.tableView.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cellId")
        navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true
        fetchJSON()
    }

    func fetchJSON(){
        let urlString = "https://www.example.com/example/example.php"
        guard let url = URL(string: urlString) else { return }
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, _, error) in
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                if let error = error {
                    print("Failed to fetch data from url", error)
                    return
                }
                guard let data = data else { return }
                do {
                    let decoder = JSONDecoder()
                    decoder.keyDecodingStrategy = .convertFromSnakeCase
                    let res = try decoder.decode([Portfolios].self, from: data)
                    let grouped = Dictionary(grouping: res, by: { $0.customer })
                    let keys = grouped.keys.sorted()
                    self.sections = keys.map({Section(name: $0, items: grouped[$0]!)})

                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        self.tableView.reloadData()
                    }
                } catch {
                    print("Failed to decode json", error)
                }

            }
            }.resume()
    }
     func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return sections.count
    }

     func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        let section = sections[section]
        return section.items.count
    }

     func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
        return sections[section].name
    }

     func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cellId", for: indexPath)
        let section = sections[indexPath.section]
        let item = section.items[indexPath.row]
        let titleStr = "\(item.serial) - \(item.manufacturer) - \(item.model)"
        cell.textLabel!.text = titleStr
        return cell
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all why do you decode the JSON twice?

No sections are displayed because the method `titleForHeaderInSection` is not implemented.

The code is not reliable anyway because the order of the sections is not guaranteed. I recommend to create another struct for the sections.

```
struct Section {
    let name : String
    let items : [Portfolios]
}

struct Portfolios: Decodable {
    let customer, serial, rma, model: String
    let manufacturer: String
}
```

Delete `portfolios` and `portfoliosDic` and declare the data source array

```
var sections = [Section]()
```

Group the JSON, sort the keys and map the dictionaries to `Section` instances

```
do {
    let decoder = JSONDecoder()
    decoder.keyDecodingStrategy = .convertFromSnakeCase
    let res = try decoder.decode([Portfolios].self, from: data)
    let grouped = Dictionary(grouping: res, by: { $0.customer })
    let keys = grouped.keys.sorted()
    self.sections = keys.map({Section(name: $0, items: grouped[$0]!)})

    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }
} catch {
    print("Failed to decode json", error)
}
```

The table view datasource and delegate methods are

```
override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return sections.count
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    let section = sections[section]
    return section.items.count
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
    return sections[section].name
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cellId", for: indexPath)
    let section = sections[indexPath.section]
    let item = section.items[indexPath.row]
    let titleStr = "\(item.serial) - \(item.manufacturer) - \(item.model)"
    cell.textLabel!.text = titleStr
    return cell
}
```

Note:

**Always** dequeue cells in `cellForRowAt`

Comment: I appreciate your help but what if instead of a UITableViewController it is just 
a UIViewController?

Comment: Can I do: `import UIKit

class CustomerViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {
    
    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!`

Comment: Yes, of course, and connect the table view in IB. In case of a `UITableViewController` you have to`override` the datasource and delegate methods

Comment: Please see the updated post. The tableview comes out empty

Comment: Please revert the controller to `UITableViewController` and override the methods. I updated the answer. And you **must not** register the cell if it's designed in the target table view. Delete the line.

Comment: Should I remove the IBOutlet? Because I get numerous errors

Comment: Yes, remove it.

Comment: Doing so builds the app but then states: `Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: '-[UITableViewController loadView] loaded the "tZh-Rh-pHX-view-NdU-X1-KnN" nib but didn't get a UITableView.' `

Comment: Clean the project: ⇧⌥⌘K. You messed it up with the class change

Comment: Same issue persists

Comment: In Interface Builder delete the custom class in the Identity Inspector of the view controller, then reassign it. My code is working. I tested it.

Comment: That seemed to do it, Is there a simple way to make the sections collapse and expand? Really appreciate your help

Comment: That's a new question.